# caller in interrupt

Tags: ruby, interrupt

What is the rule for the content of `caller` called from within an interruption? When I run the following code:

```
File: test

1| def a; b end
2| def b; c end
3| def c; loop{sleep(1)} end
4| def d; e end
5| def e; f end
6| def f; puts caller; exit end
7| Signal.trap("INT"){d}
8| a
```

and type `Ctrl+c` during execution, I get the following output:

```
test:5:in `e'
test:4:in `d'
test:7:in `block in <main>'
test:3:in `call'
test:3:in `sleep'
test:3:in `block in c'
test:3:in `loop'
test:3:in `c'
test:2:in `b'
test:1:in `a'
test:8:in `<main>'
```

What is the rule that composes this call stack? I see two instances of `<main>`. They are combined in some way. I am not exactly sure how. Also, what happens when there are multiple threads running? How is it determined which threads are combined or ignored in the call stack called from an interruption?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what "rule" you're looking for. Signals are received asynchronously and queued by the ruby runtime; between each primitive execution step (AST node in 1.8, byte-code instruction in YARV), the runtime checks if there are pending signals and invokes the bound handler for them.  Invoking the handler doesn't modify the prior existing call stack.  If your handler were to return, program execution will pick up again where it left off.

Here's the execution flow exhibited by your example: In main, you call `Signal.trap` handing it a block `{d}` which is defined in main. You then call `a`, which calls `b`, which calls `c`, which loops forever calling the block defined in c `{sleep(1)}` which calls `sleep`.

You send a SIGINT and the runtime receives the signal and calls the block you registered as the INT handler (`test:7:in 'block in <main>'`), which calls `d`, which calls `e`, which calls `f`, which prints the call stack you see and exits.

Since most of the time is spent in sleep, that's the most likely execution point where the INT handler gets invoked. However, if the INT signal comes in just right, you might see the same call stack with one or both of these lines omitted:

```
test:3:in `sleep'
test:3:in `block in c'
```